# In SwiftUI, why does a Spacer push the text outside of the TextEditor frame?

Tags: swiftui

In the following code, why does the frame of the TextEditor stay within the safe area, while the text is pushed up to the top of the screen, beyond the safe area, and outside of the TextEditor's frame?

```
VStack {
    TextEditor(text: $myText)
        .frame(height: 200)
        .border(Color.red)
    Spacer()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `.padding()`to adjust the text frame.

Adding padding is like adding `textContainerInset` in UITextView.

Like this

```
struct TestFrameView: View {
    
    @State private var myText: String = "Hello"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $myText)
                .padding() //<-- here or .padding(.top, 0.1) for zero space.
                .frame(height: 200)
                .border(Color.red)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that does fix it, thank you for the answer. I still don't understand why the text is pushed out of the frame though. Does the Spacer act on the TextEditor frame and the text inside of the TextEditor differently?

Comment: @rawbee I think it's a 50% bug. yes, it like a TextEditor frame and inside the Text because by setting padding you can change the position of Text.